# How to access RadMenuItem added during runtime from Javascript / Jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, telerik

I am adding RadMenuItem to ContextMenu during runtime to Telerik RadFileExplorer like below :
I want to know how i can access this radmenuitem button using JS/ Jquery. I want to enable/disable this button at client side :

```
RadMenuItem lastModifiedDate = new RadMenuItem("Last Modified Date");
lastModifiedDate.PostBack = false;               
lastModifiedDate.Value = "LastModifiedDate";
FileExplorer.TreeView.ContextMenus[0].Items.Add(lastModifiedDate);
FileExplorer.GridContextMenu.Items.Add(lastModifiedDate.Clone());
```

---

aspx:

```
 <telerik:RadFileExplorer runat="server" ID="FileExplorer" </telerik:RadFileExplorer>
```

Updated Code :

```
function attachHandlers(explorer, args) {
            var toolbar = explorer.get_toolbar();
            toolbar.add_buttonClicked(toolbarClicked);
            //support for grid context menu
            var gridContextMenu = explorer.get_gridContextMenu();  
            var menuItem = gridContextMenu.get_items().getItem(0).set_enabled(false);       
            gridContextMenu.add_itemClicked(gridContextMenuClicked); 
           
        }

 function gridContextMenuClicked(toolbar, args)
            {          
             var buttonValue = args.get_item().get_value();
             if (buttonValue == "LastModifiedDate")
             {
                //Do Something          
               
             } 
         }

function toolbarClicked(toolbar, args) {              
            if (args.get_item().get_value() == "folderCommand") 
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this article: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/fileexplorer/how-to/adding-custom-command-buttons

Basically, you subscribe to the OnClientLoad event of the radFileExplorer:

```
<telerik:RadFileExplorer RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadFileExplorer1" runat="server" OnClientLoad="attachHandlers">
</telerik:RadFileExplorer>
```

And in its event handler, you can get access to the context menu (and its items) like this:

```
<script>
function attachHandlers(explorer, args)
{
    //support for grid context menu
    var gridContextMenu = explorer.get_gridContextMenu();

    // disable the menu item if some conditions are met
    var menuItem = gridContextMenu.get_items().getItem(0).disable();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you , i reached this point but i want to disable one of the context menu option on context menu click event in below function and enable it back on click of OnClientItemSelected - function gridContextMenuClicked(toolbar, args)
{
    var buttonValue = args.get_item().get_value();
    if (buttonValue == "custom_Menu")
        alert("custom context menu item clicked");
}

Comment: This line returns undefined -  var menuItem = gridContextMenu.get_items().getItem(0).disable();

Comment: can you check what exactly is undefined on that line - is it the contextMenu, or get_items() return 0 items?

Comment: .disable() is making it undefined , context menu , get_items() return proper items

Comment: and getItem(0) also returns an item? can you try set_enabled(false) instead of disable()? if it still doesn't work - can you update your question with the code you have?

Comment: set_enabled(false) also returned undefined, getItem(0) returns a item. Updated the code above

Comment: Are you sure the null is not coming from these 2 lines (which I believe you copy/pasted directly from the documentation link: var toolbar = explorer.get_toolbar();
            toolbar.add_buttonClicked(toolbarClicked); - especially if you have not defined toolbarClicked event handler?

Comment: I have toolbarclick function defined and it is working perfectly fine. The problem is only when setting it to disabled it is becoming undefined.

Comment: I think you have a missing closing } at gridContextMenuClicked handler. It does not give such error to me.

Comment: That was a typo...i have proper closing in my code. You are not getting undefined ?? Can you share your code ?

Comment: it is exactly as in my answer + on Page_Load I am adding a menu item like in your code. So for me the .disable() fires correctly, and then I can call item.get_enabled() and it returns false, but the thing is if I right click again - the item is not disabled